# In what page life phase should I add external javascript?

Tags: asp.net, .net

If I want to add external javascript file into an aspx page in back end code page, in what page life should I add it? Page_Load? or Page_PreInit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't mind where you put it. I usually put them in the the Page_PreRender event.

There are a couple of reason why I do this.

1. you want to conditionally add Javascript resources based on some condition in your page, so your need your whole page to be loaded. The PreRender event is the perfect time to check some conditions because everything should be loaded and ready to be renderd.
2. If you for example add them in the PreInit and in your PageLoad you decide to redirect to a different page you executed unnecessary code.

So even if both points do not apply to the situation I still put them in the PageRender as it's the guideline for the whole project.